# Why is the keyboard not showing?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I'm having trouble getting a soft keyboard to open when an edit text field gains focus. It works on a device but not the emulator. I have a setOnFocusedChangedListener trying to handle it and I think the code is getting called. Also, a grey bar appears at the bottom of the screen.

Can anyone give me some hints as to what to look for? This is the type of thing I've been trying:

```
    mainPassEdit =  (EditText)mainPrefsPasswordDialog.findViewById(R.id.prefs_main_pass_dialog_edit_text);
    mainPassEdit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                Log.v(TAG, "has focus");
                InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                mgr.toggleSoftInput(0, 0);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having an issue with the emulator but not a real device, check your emulated device settings. In Android Virtual Device Manager > Device Definitions > [Device] > Edit..., make sure that Buttons are set to "Software" not "Hardware". The keyboard will not pop up if you are emulating a device with a hardware keyboard.

Comment: Thanks but I see no options for Buttons and I haven't set up a hardware keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this version of writing it:

```
EditText yourEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

By referencing the EditText directly you will have more control over showing it and linking it to the EditText

Comment: Yeah, it produces the same results. Thanks though.